# starting a program as user from windows-service

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, service, messagebox

i would like to start a program as user from within a windows-service.

Is this possible?

Background is that i need to display a MessageBox and would simply do something like

```
            MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
```

in the program.

Comment: This is almost always a sign of bad design somewhere, what exactly are you trying to achieve in having a GUI on your service? There is nearly always a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having my program in autostart on logon, but it should also be possible to start a program from within a service using e.g. CreateProcessWithLogonW.

Answer (score 0):

This will not behave as you expect it to.
The windows-service is most likely running as LocalSystem, and tied to Session 0.  Even if you set the service to allow interaction with the desktop it will most likely not show on the session you're after.